# SQLite database not recognizing one of my columns

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to create an SQLite database in an Android app, but my app keeps crashing and LogCat gives the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.zebra.leadcapture, PID: 15427
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table lead_capture_database has no column named EntryNumber (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO lead_capture_database(EntryNumber,BarcodeData,Notes) VALUES('0','','');
#################################################################
Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
(table lead_capture_database has no column named EntryNumber (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO lead_capture_database(EntryNumber,BarcodeData,Notes) VALUES('0','','');)
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
public void addNewEntry(String barcodeDataString, String notesString) {
    leadDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(database_name,MODE_PRIVATE,null);

    String create_string = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + database_name
            + "(EntryNumber TEXT,BarcodeData TEXT,Notes TEXT);";
    String insert_string = "INSERT INTO " + database_name + "(EntryNumber,BarcodeData,Notes) VALUES('" + entryCount + "','" + barcodeDataString + "','" + notesString + "');";
    leadDatabase.execSQL(create_string);
    leadDatabase.execSQL(insert_string);

    entryCount++;
}
```

Why is it not recognizing EntryNumber as a column?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS-  any chance you created one previously with 2 columns?

Comment: I must have during testing. I added a DROP TABLE that I'll remove now and it fixed the problem. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in the comments above, but for future reference: I deleted the app from my device and reinstalled it through Android Studio which fixed the problem. I had previously been writing the app with a SQLite database without that column but with the same name. I imagine changing the string I was using for the name would have had the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You added that column after table was created. In this case, that column is not added into database. If you drop the table and recreate it, it will fix your problem without uninstalling the app. Also you can create a method for migration.